# os kernel paramete missing semmni

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle 11gR2 on oracle linux 7. 
As per the documentation given in

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7 there i think i have properly configured it.

but unfortunately i get the following error.

[image]

but when i see parameters with `sysctl -p` i get

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 262144
net.core.wmem_max = 1048586
```

or

```
sysctl -a | grep "kernel.sem"
```

gives

```
kernel.sem = 250    32000   100 128
kernel.sem_next_id = -1
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.ens192.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
```

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your installation style,

Firstly, log as root

`$ su root`

and then check whether the resource limits are in the recomended range for the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` as below ( *if not, you need to update the values in that file* ) :

```
--# the soft limit for the stack setting
$ ulimit -Ss
10240
$ ulimit -Hs
32768

--# the soft and the hard limits for the number of processes available to a user
$ ulimit -Su
2047
$ ulimit -Hu
16384

--# he soft and hard limits for the file descriptor setting
$ ulimit -Sn
4096
$ ulimit -Hn
65536
```

if the problem still persists, and you use version before `11.2.0.4`(*there might be a bug*),

you might meet such situation, re-install at least with version `11.2.0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1026584/the-shmmax-value-is-too-large-when-installing-oracle-11g-on-rhel7)

there is a bug in RHEL 7 with 11.2.0.4, if you really need to install 11.2.0.4 on RHEL 7, you should really think about it again, otherwise you can go ahead with 12c.